# Using VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH to run a Lottery

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I'm using Excel to run a sort of lottery.

The spreadsheet columns are set up thus:

COL1:Person Name; COL2: Chosen Number A; COL3: Chosen Number B; COL4: Chosen Number C

There is then a set of data, generated using RAND() and ROUND, that gives 3 winning numbers, each between 0 and 10.

What I'm trying to do is identify a winner, by using VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH, or some combination, or other function, to identify the winning person, so that there is a single cell that returns the name of the winner.

The added complexity is that by looking up each of the numbers individually by column, an individual selection of, say, 1,4,8, isn't a winning selection against a randomly selection of say, 4,8,1.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate numbers to additionalcolumn so it will contain string "1,4,8," and then perform a VLOOKUP for concatenated in the same way winning numbers.
By the way, this solution will show only first person, but isn't it possible that several persons guessed same numbers and won?

Comment: This is a good solution and an excellent question about the possibility of multiple winners.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a 3-digit number, by far the easiest thing to do is to use the formula

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,999)
```

You can select the cells and then enter (via the format dialog accessible by right-clicking) the custom format `000` if you want it to display as 3 digits so that e.g. `7` displays as `007`. This will allow you to directly use `VLOOKUP` on a single value. @kipar asks an excellent question about potential multiple winners.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the abovementioned solution and it was quite easy. After your 4 columns, you add one column with

=TEXT(B1;0)&TEXT(C1;0)&TEXT(D1;0)

which combines the number to one string. Then you put your winning number in a cell of preference mine was M28 and the value was 123. After your first five columns you use the following formula.

=IF.ERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$4;SMALL(IF(E$1:E$4=TEXT($M$28;0);ROW(E$1:E$4));RI-OW());1);"")

The IF.ERROR is used to put a blank when there are no multiple winners. The index is used to get the winners out of your first column, that'w why there's a one at the end. The small is used to find the first occurence of the winner. You also have to enter it as an array formula so press ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter when the formula is completed. I hope this answer is satisfying.

PS. For extra information on the use of this function go here: http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/12/09/multiple-occurrences-lookup-and-extraction/